# Bash - how to avoid command "eval set --" evaluating variables

Tags: bash, variables, unix, cmd, eval

I just write a little bash script for managing multiple parallels ssh commands.
In order to parse arguments I use this piece of code :

```
#!/bin/bash

# replace long arguments
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        --help)           args="${args}-h ";;
        --host|-hS)       args="${args}-s ";;
        --cmd)            args="${args}-c ";;
        *) [[ "${arg:0:1}" == "-" ]] && delim='' || delim="\""
           args="${args}${delim}${arg}${delim} ";;
    esac
done

echo "args before eval : $args"
eval set -- $args
echo "args after eval  : $args"

while getopts "hs:c:" OPTION; do
    echo "optarg : $OPTARG"
    case $OPTION in
    h)  usage; exit 0;;
    s)  servers_array+=("$OPTARG");;
    c)  cmd="$OPTARG";;
    esac
done
```

So I can use for instance -s, --host or -hS for the same result.
Everything works fine except one thing.

If I put a variable in argument it will be evaluated.

#### Explanations

```
./test.sh -s SERVER -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

1. `cmd` should be assigned to `echo $HOSTNAME` but because of the `eval set` cmd is in fact assigned to `echo server1` (the value of the variable)
2. If I comment the line `eval set -- $args` I cannot use long options (--cmd) but `cmd` is assigned to `echo $HOSTNAME` as expected

Is there any solution to avoid eval set / getopts to evaluate variables ?
So to to have the same behavior as 2. but with long options available.

#### Examples

with eval set

```
./test.sh -s SERVER -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
args before eval : -s "SERVER" -c "echo $HOSTNAME"
args after eval  : -s "SERVER" -c "echo $HOSTNAME"
optarg : SERVER
optarg : echo server1
```

without eval set (line `eval set -- $args` commented)

```
./test.sh -s SERVER -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
args before eval : -s "SERVER" -c "echo $HOSTNAME"
args after eval  : -s "SERVER" -c "echo $HOSTNAME"
optarg : SERVER
optarg : echo $HOSTNAME
```

Comment: Eww. In general, argument lists should be built with list-native data structures -- arrays, not strings.

Comment: ...granted, SSH passes a string to the remote system as a command, but the tools to convert arrays to shell-quoted strings are robust and reliable.

Comment: ...all that said, my suggestion would be not to use getopts at all; it just makes your code harder to read and more complex than some simple, POSIX-sh-compliant shell-neutral idioms. See BashFAQ #35: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: Also, this question is substantially related to BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: `eval` is necessary when arguments contain spaces. You will have to quote the variable too. I.e. `eval set -- "$args"`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you note, [`eval` is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) -- and there's no need to use it here.

```
#!/bin/bash

# make args an array, not a string
args=( )

# replace long arguments
for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
        --help)           args+=( -h ) ;;
        --host|-hS)       args+=( -s ) ;;
        --cmd)            args+=( -c ) ;;
        *)                args+=( "$arg" ) ;;
    esac
done

printf 'args before update : '; printf '%q ' "$@"; echo
set -- "${args[@]}"
printf 'args after update  : '; printf '%q ' "$@"; echo

while getopts "hs:c:" OPTION; do
    : "$OPTION" "$OPTARG"
    echo "optarg : $OPTARG"
    case $OPTION in
    h)  usage; exit 0;;
    s)  servers_array+=("$OPTARG");;
    c)  cmd="$OPTARG";;
    esac
done
```

That is to say: When building up a command line, append individual items to an array; you can then expand that array, quoted, without risking either evaluation or undesired behavior via effects of string-splitting, glob expansion, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help with little improvement I manage to do what I want ;) I don't know why I haven't think about an array before !

Comment: Am I missing something with the `for` loop? How does `arg` get a value? Should it be `for arg in "$@"; do`?

Comment: @smeep, `"$@"` is the default thing for `for` to iterate over, and is used with `for varname do` (I shouldn't have used the `;`, which POSIX doesn't require to work -- allowing it is a bash extension) in absence of any more specific description of what to iterate over.

Comment: @erenon, `--cmd=*) cmd=${arg#*=} ;;` will assign `foo` to the variable named `cmd`. I don't personally use or recommend use of `getopts`; I only answered with it here because that's what the OP wanted. For what I _personally recommend_, see [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Comment: Why `: "$OPTION" "$OPTARG"`?

Comment: @CervEd, when you run with `set -x` / `bash -x yourscript` for tracing, that'll log both values.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. This a very good answer, but there's a lot of logging going on. I think the answer could possibly be even better with those parts labelled as such

Comment: That's literally the _only_ line of logging I added -- the rest of it's in the original question.